# Exit code from a batch file converted to an exe is not returning 0 when called by Process.Start()

Tags: c#, batch-file

Summary:
A c# app is supposed to call gpg.exe to encrypt a file before sending it out. In testing we found a computer configuration where gpg consistently fails.

The goal I have is to create a wrapper batch file that calls GPG but prints the command line args to an output file, and have our app call this.

The C# code for calling the command:

```
public static int StartProcess(string command, string arguments, int waitForProcess)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
                startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
            else
                startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, arguments);

            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();
```

Note that I have no control over what filename the system is expecting as this is production code: we are expecting command to be C:\Program Files\gnupg\gpg.

I renamed the real gpg.exe to gpg2.exe, and created a batch file (ignore the terrible batch code unless relevant please. It's supposed to be a quick diagnostic rather than a robust solution):

```
@echo off

ECHO %* > "C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpgoutput.txt"

"C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 >> gpgoutput.txt

if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo 1 >> gpgoutput.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 0 echo 0 >> gpgoutput.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 2 echo 2 >> gpgoutput.txt

exit /b 0
```

Turns out p.Start() will throw an error and isn't able to find the batch file. So, I downloaded bat_to_exe_converter to convert the bat file to exe format. I Saved the file as GPG.exe

Process flow should now be C# app calls 'gpg.exe' > calls gpg2.exe and logs the variables/exit code.

This code runs fine from a command prompt but when called from the c# app, the exit code is 9211 and I can see that the gpgoutput.txt file is not created, implying that it doesn't actually run 'gpg.exe'

Why doesn't the above code get executed correctly from my C# application? My only thought is that this must be related to either permissions or the directory somehow.

EDIT: I have tried manually setting command to C:\Program Files\gnupg\gpg.bat and the code works fine. The issue seems to be caused by 
a) I get an error if it is only looking for C:\Program Files\gnupg\gpg and the file is saved as gpg.bat "the system cannot find the file specified"
b) If I convert the batch to gpg.exe, the system CAN find the file, but gives exit code ~9200. Is this the fault of the exe converter?

Comment: The issue lay with bat_to_exe_converter--using a different exe converter fixed the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not use the batch-file-converted-to-exe. All that's going to do is make things harder.

Second, you should be able to run a batch file using Process. With `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` set to `true`, I would expect it to "just work". But even barring that, you should be able to execute the command-line interpreter, as "cmd.exe /c ..." where the "..." is the full command to execute the batch file. If you are still having problems there, you might ask that as a different question.

Finally, as far as your wrapper batch file goes, the most obvious problem is that you are explicitly setting the exit code to 0 with `exit /b 0`. If you want the exit code from the gpg2.exe process to be returned, you need to save it immediately after running gpg2.exe (e.g. `set EXITCODE=%errorlevel%`), and then use that value when you exit the batch file (e.g. `exit /b %EXITCODE%`).

If you return the actual exit code for the process from your batch file, then the C# program should be able to read the code just fine.

(Saving the value immediately ensures that other statements later in the batch file, which could also affect the errorlevel value, won't interfere with you returning the correct exit code.)

Comment: Hi Peter -- the problem here is that I absolutely CANNOT change the above StartProcess code: this is software that is currently in production and the issue seems to be specific to one user's computer set up. The goal is just to log the command variables being input into GPG and to log GPG's exit code.

I agree that it should 'just work'--when I change the value of command in the debugger to explicitly point to my batch file I have no issue at all and everything works as expected. When I run the file as an exe that is when I get exit code 9211--even after explicitly setting my exit code to 0

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...that wasn't at all clear to me from the original question. That said, I still think you're asking for trouble adding the extra layer of the batch-to-exe conversion. It's just one more thing that can go wrong (and in this case, seems to be). Since you can't change the original `Process`-related code, I would write your _own_ wrapper (in C#) that you can run via the production code, and which runs the batch file. Then you have complete control over the processes being run.

Comment: One more thing:  if the problem is on only one PC, it may be better to just fix that PC. :) It could be as simple as the PATH environment variable not being set correctly, but at the very least it seems like that's a clearly solvable problem, even if the solution isn't immediately apparent.

Comment: That's the true issue here however--set-up looks fine, GPG runs correctly from command prompt and homedir has been specified correctly. The only Blackbox whose input/output we can't see is what our code is getting/sending through to GPG.

We could write up a C# wrapper but the whole point of this exercise was that we don't want to have to test/write/re-publish the software at this client for the sake of one user. The goal was that this would be a quick and dirty short-term solution and that better debugging of the encryption process would be more long term goal. If this isn't working though...

Comment: Writing your own wrapper is not more having to test/write/re-publish the software than is using the batch-to-exe utility you found. Heck, you could've probably written the wrapper in the same time it took to do a web search for the tool you wound up using.

Comment: Turns out the whole issue was that the bat to exe converter I used was bad--different converter resolved my problem. 

Marking this as the correct answer as it would be a better way to go about solving the original problem